# Add CSS to a JavaScript button

Tags: javascript, css, button

On my project I use JS Buttons a lot, I can't find a way to add CSS to them. Can you help?

```
leftBtn = document.createElement('button');
leftBtn.innerText = "<";
rightBtn = document.createElement('button');
rightBtn.innerText = ">";
fireBtn = document.createElement('button');
fireBtn.innerText = "*";
```

Using CSS classes to change buttons:
`<button` *class="btn"*`>default button</button>`

[Class used](https://picturepan2.github.io/spectre/elements/buttons.html)

Comment: Simply add the CSS property you want like `leftBtn.marginLeft = "20px"`.....

Comment: Does this work with classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this code to add a css class to each button:

```
 leftBtn.className = "leftOne";
 rightBtn.className = "rightOne";
 fireBtn.className = "fireOne";
```

Then you can use regular css to style them.

Comment: I want something like this: <button class="btn">default button</button> except I can use class="btn" on it so it has the CSS style of the button

Comment: then in my example just change leftOne, rightOne and fireOne to btn and then each will have the btn css class assigned to it.

Comment: `leftBtn.className = "btn-primary";
rightBtn.className = "btn-primary"; 
fireBtn.className = "btn-primary";` Doesn't work. (https://picturepan2.github.io/spectre/elements/buttons.html)

Comment: ?? Doing so assigns the "btn-primary" css class to each button an allows you to style the button by using `<style> .btn-primary {/*some styles here*/}; </style>`  What doesn't work about it?

Comment: btn-primary is supposed to be used on it. btn-primary is a built-in css style. It just needs added to the button so it has the style.

Comment: I see on the page you linked to that you need to use "btn btn-primary" so use `leftBtn.className = "btn btn-primary"; rightBtn.className = "btn btn-primary"; fireBtn.className = "btn btn-primary";`

Comment: It would work, you are now correctly setting the "btn and btn-primary" classes on the buttons but when you reference the spectre.min.css rather than just spectre.min.css in your link tag you need to reference it as css/spectre.min.css  so currently your spectre styles aren't getting loaded.

Comment: It's there but its in the css folder and you are trying to reference it in the root folder

Comment: Just add whatever other styles you want in your main.css.  Eg. `.btn .btn-primary {width:60px}`  If you need more help with the use of css you can start a new question.  (remember to accept my answer if it answered your original question.)

Answer (score 1):

You could add a class to your buttons, and then add any styling in CSS:

```
leftBtn.className = "class_name"
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to use the className to your Javascript:

EXAMPLE:

```
leftBtn.className = "name";
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use for example :

```
leftBtn.style.color = "blue";
```

Lear more about in https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style

Answer (score 1):

In general, there are two main ways to do that.

The first one using inline styles, just keep in mind that inline style has the highest precedence in a document.

```
elt.style.color = '...'
```

or

```
elt.setAttribute('style', '...')
```

[More info here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style)

The second is by using the class name. You can simply define a class name and write CSS for this class name.

```
element.className.add = 'your-class-name'
```

then

```
.your-class-name { color: red }
```

In a second way, you can manage class names by using methods like `add`, `remove`, `toggle`

[More info here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Answer (score 0):

Just do something like this

```
leftBtn.style.marginLeft = '20px'
rightBtn.style.marginLeft = '20px'
```

I guess it

Answer (score 0):

```
var leftBtn = document.createElement('button');
leftBtn.innerText = "<";
leftBtn.className = "test_style"; // Set class name
leftBtn.style.color = "#000"; // You can also set style properties inline
```

...

Here is a playground:

https://jsfiddle.net/u5hojsgb/